Film that ends with protagonist triggering avalanche suicide when cornered
Saw this in mid 70's. Might have been a slight ripoff of, or at least influenced by, Jeremiah Johnson. Was not that movie, however. I remember seeing it in a theatre, but I was probably < 10yrs old.
The protagonist is wrongfully accused of a crime. I think he is a hermit or social outcast being scapegoated for something he does earlier in the movie. The viewer understands his motivation to be based on sympathy for someone or something being wronged by one of the tough guys who is embarrassed by what he does. So this tough guy frames him. 
Setting is a wintry mountainous area in North America, possibly Canadian Rockies, possibly near Alaska. Rugged people. It seemed like it was set in the past, like 1800's, but that area was probably like that until fairly recent times.
The avalanche is triggered by the protagonist pointing his rifle up at an overhang or drift directly above him, waiting a moment, and then firing. I don't think anyone else is caught in it.

Is the avalance the only thing you remember from the movie ?

Welcome to Movies & TV. Please try to add anything that may help identification. Are there any other plot details you remember or descriptions you can give? Anything at all? You have to give much more than that. Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question.

This is getting better, we now have a small plot and a final scene. I know it's hard to remember if you were < 10 years old. Any actor you can recall ? Any producer/studio ?

I have watched several movies hoping I found it. Still scarred by the emotional toll of that movie at such a young age.

I think we have enough description to start looking around. This is much better than your first draft :) Good job !

@davidjmcclelland The "downvote sting" goes away because I remove my downvote now that you improved your question quite a bit. ;-)

Just to be clear, the film ends with protag setting off an avalanche that kills them all or just himself? Was it explosives? Noise (like firing a gun or something)? Do you remember how it happened? Also, wouldn't he only be scapegoated if he didn't do the thing earlier? You're doing fine, but I suggest taking the Tour, if for no other reasons than it only takes a couple minutes, it's useful info, and you'll get another badge.

Here it is. One of the comments is from another who saw this movie as a youngster and spent 20 years looking for it! Challenge To Be Free from 1975, when I was 8.




You might want to elaborate in hich way this fits the details from the question in order to flesh out this answer a little more.

I am the OP, and this is the movie. The scene described in the question title is linked to.
